# Simultaneous reading and writing to registers

Tags: vhdl, mips, fpga, cpu-architecture

I'm planning to design a MIPS-like CPU in VHDL on a FPGA. The CPU will have a classic five stage pipeline without forwarding and hazard prevention. In the computer architecture course I learned that the first MIPS-CPUs used to read from the register file on rising clock edge and write on falling clock edge. The FPGA I'm using doesn't support using rising and falling clock edge at the same time (regarding reading and writing to registers), so I can't exactly do like the original MIPS and have to do it all on rising clock edge.

So, here comes the part where I'm having a problem. The instruction writes back to the register in the write back stage. The write back stage sends the data directly to the decode stage. Another instruction in the decode stage wants to read the same register that also the write back stage wants to write.

What happens in this case? Does the decode stage take the new value for the instruction or the old value that is still in the register file?

Comment: "Most FPGAs don't support falling clock edge" ... what a curious idea, where did you read that? what they don't support is clocking the same register on both clock edges (and the exceptions are generally I/O blocks)...However, reading and writing on the same clock edge is fine, as the read and write data are separate signals. If you move te registers into a BlockRam, be sure to read its data regarding simultaneous read and write (usually on separate ports).

Comment: You are right. The user guide for the board was not so clear in this point. The FPGA does support falling edge but not using both edges at the same time.

Comment: I think if you read the old value, then you need one more cycle of result forwarding (reading the new value provides forwarding through the register file).

Comment: Reading and writing simultaneously in a register on the same clock edge is the basics of synchronous design, and especially of pipeline architectures. Consider registers as still cameras. On the rising (falling) clock edge they instantaneously take a picture of their input and they reflect it on their output for the whole following clock period. The output of the register propagates across the glue logic and, after a while, the signals stabilise. On the next rising (falling) clock edge the registers sample these new inputs and the process repeats.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I understand how D-flip-flops are working and how I should use them. My question goes to a higher level and I'm asking about the 32bit-registers in a register file.  I have edited the question so it should be (hopefully) clearer now.

Comment: How about a writeback register WR (e.g. cache).  The write back to the register file [RFn] occurs on the rising edge of next cycle from WR.  If next cycle wants read of same register, it comes from WR if it matches, RFn otherwise.

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks for the hint. It appears that the course material was wrong. The diagram there showed that the write signals from the write back stage went back to the buffer for fetch/decode. Therefore it would have a cycle delay. Correctly the write signals should directly go to the register file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A register file that fits in the decode stage of the classic five stage design consists of a triple port RAM (or two dual port RAM) and two muxers and comparators. The comparators and muxers are required to bypass the data coming from the write-back stage. This is needed as the write data is written into the triple port RAM in the next cycle. Because the signals coming from the write-back stage are synchronous, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what do you understand by the term "register". Or more specifically, how do you would like to map the register bank to the FPGA.

The easiest but not so efficient way is to map each MIPS register to several flip-flops according to the register size. You can update these flip-flops at only clock-edge (e.g. falling edge). After that you can read the new content at any time also known as asynchronous read. This solution is not so efficient because the multiplexer to select one MIPS register from the register bank requires a lot of logic resources.

If you have an  FPGA where the LUTs can be used as distributed memory, then almost all of the logic resources for the multiplexers can be saved. Distributed memory typically provides an asynchronous read too (and a synchronous write of course). Please read the vender documentation of the synthesis tool on how to describe this type of memory for synthesis.

Last but not least, you can map the full register bank to on-chip block memory. These typically provide only a synchronous read, i.e., reading starts at a clock-edge. (Of course, they also provide only a synchronous write). However, these are typically dual-ported RAMs. Thus, you can write at the falling edge at one port and read with the rising at on the other port. Please read, the documentation of your FPGA on the timing of the write. For example, on some Altera FPGAs the writing is delayed to the next opposite edge (here rising-edge) of the clock.